# Java: Creating a 2D ArrayList to store an integer and string?

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I need to store 2 arrays of values that are connected to each other. The arrays consists of a set of strings and a set of integer/double values. The size of the data are not fixed.

An example:

```
Data 1: AA, 13    
Data 2: BB, 6    
Data 3: GG, 2
```

I am trying to look at 2D Arrays. Is there a better way to store the values? There's a possibilities that I might need multidimensional arrays to store the values as well. Can anyone point me in the right direction or show me a way to create the 2D arrays and how to add/retrieve the elements?

Comment: Do you need to differentiate between ints and doubles? Or can it be all pairs of String,Double ?

Comment: It's either pairs of String-double or String-integers. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be *far* better to use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Maps have key-value pairs, so you could naturally store Strings and Integers in this manner.

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Comment: Map has two type parameters, set only has one.

Comment: Ah, that's right.  I must've been working with something else for far too long.

Comment: Hi Makoto, is it possible to use Map to store a set of 3 values like String-integer-integer (AA, 3, 6) or String-integer-double(KK, 6, 2.5)?

Comment: Yes - instead of storing a single Integer object, you would store a `List<Integer>`.

Comment: Unfortunately Makoto, Map only allows unique keys and I'm afraid my data might contain same values. It's a great learning experience nevertheless.

Comment: By using the `List<Integer>` as your value set, you can append values to the end of that key's list.  This means you can have more than one value for a single key.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use like this there are two ways if you want only ArrayList as a datastructure
create a class like this :

```
    public Class Data{
    private String myString;
    private Integer myInteger;
    public String getMyString() {
        return myString;
    }

    public void setMyString(String myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    public Integer getMyInteger() {
        return myInteger;
    }

    public void setMyInteger(Integer myInteger) {
        this.myInteger = myInteger;
    }
}
List<Data> list = new ArrayList<Data>();

or else you can use like this

List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```